# Distorb/warp texture in andengine

Tags: java, android, andengine

I'm interested what methods of AndEngine GLES1 i must used to achieve the effect of wave for my texture.
I need the effect as there http://hge.relishgames.com/demos.html example 3. Distortion mesh.
What i must used or even what methods can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no pre-made class for this. You would create a subclass of Entity or Shape that has a grid of vertices, of which you manually transform the positions so they behave like whatever you want to visualize.

Depending on the effect you can achieve the same results with a Shader in GLES2. =)